# Can't run debugging on previously used port on IIS Express

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, iis-express

recently I decided to move my ASP NET Core solution to new place, and obviously, something went wrong.

In `launchSettings.json` file there were specified:

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53985",
  "sslPort": 44325
}
```

When I moved whole solution, together with this file, I got connection reset error (yes, it was for SSL).

When I changed it to something new, eg. `44330`, it worked.

Using `netsh http show sslcert` I see that there `44330` is specified, but `44325` isn't. So why I can't re-use it?

After moving many projects frequently, I will run out from ports to use! What's the remedy for that?

Comment: "Using netsh http show sslcert I see that there 44330 is specified, but 44325 isn't". That means something mistakenly removed the necessary certificate mapping for port 44325, and you can easily recreate it via netsh command.

Comment: @LexLi So the error is that I don't have certificate for 44325?

Comment: Correct. If no certificate mapping is there for port 44325, HTTPS connection must be reset by Windows.

Comment: @LexLi Could post an answer, because I'd like to have this post in my questions history for future reference :) And I'd like it to have accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comment with more details.

Requests to `http://localhost:44325` can be reset if HTTP.sys cannot find a valid certificate bind to that port. Since you confirmed with `netsh` that indeed such a certificate is missing, we then know the exact cause of the reset error.

The initial certificate mapping was created for 44300-44399 by IIS Express installer, so VS always assumes port 44325 has a certificate associated. However, it is pretty difficult to tell why now the certificate mapping is missing, as anything can change HTTP.sys settings.

The solution is to recreate a certificate mapping with `netsh` for port 44325 (you can refer to other certificate mappings to learn what parameters you need).